# Alpaca api stock data JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python

I am able to read in a csv file of stocks from the QQQ etf into a list and call price data from alpaca api on the list when using another csv file from Nasdaq with stock names I receive json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

What am I missing?

```
import config, requests, json

lines = open('data/nasdaq.csv').readlines()

symbols = [line.split(',')[0].strip() for line in lines][1:]
symbols = ",".join(symbols)

day_bars_url = '{}/day?symbols={}&limit=1'.format(config.BARS_URL, symbols)

r = requests.get(day_bars_url, headers=config.HEADERS)

print(json.dumps(r.json(), indent=4))
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzuOx.png)

Comment: It appears the data you are receiving isn't a valid json. Can you post the raw response data?

Comment: First two lines of data from symbols variable: A,AA,AACG,AACQ,AACQU,AACQW,AAIC,AAIC.PRB,AAIC.PRC,AAL,AAMC,AAME,AAN,AAOI,AAON,AAP,AAPL,AAT,AAU,AAWW,AB,ABB,ABBV,ABC,ABCB,ABCL,ABCM,ABEO,ABEV,ABG,ABIO,ABM,ABMD,ABNB,ABR,ABR.PRA,ABR.PRB,ABR.PRC,ABST,ABT,ABTX,ABUS,AC,ACA,ACAC,ACACU,ACACW,ACAD,ACB,AC

Comment: The response.Your ```r.content``` or ```r.text```

Comment: Returns same symbols but ends with: 'b'<html>\r\n<head><title>414 Request-URI Too Large</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>414 Request-URI Too Large</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'

Comment: There's your answer... ```414 Request-URI Too Large```. Your api request is incorrect for the api. Take a look at the documentation to see the limits.